# How to convert a symbolic expression to a Octave function from the Symbolic Package?

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math, numerical-computing

#### How to convert a symbolic expression to a Octave function from the Symbolic Package?

After installing the symbolic package on octave with `pkg install -forge symbolic`. Using the symbolic package on octave I may write this:

```
octave> pkg load symbolic;
octave> a = sym( "a" );
octave> int ( a^2 + csc(a) )
```

which will result in:

```
ans = (sym)

   3
  a    log(cos(a) - 1)   log(cos(a) + 1)
  -- + --------------- - ---------------
  3           2                 2
```

But how to do this Integral (int(1)) symbolic result just above to became a valuable function like this below?

```
function x = f( x )

    x = x^3/3 + log( cos(x) - 1 )/2 - log( cos(x) + 1 )/2

end

f(3)

# Which evaluates to: 11.6463 +  1.5708i
```

I want to take the symbolic result from `int ( a^2 + csc(a) )`, and call result(3), to compute it at 3, i.e., return the numeric value 11.6463 +  1.5708i, from the symbolic expression integral `a^2 + csc(a)`. Basically, how to use the symbolic expression as numerically evaluable expressions? It is the as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364660/matlab-how-do-i-convert-multivariable-symbolic-expression-to-a-function-that-fm) for Matlab.

References:

1. http://octave.sourceforge.net/symbolic/index.html
2. [How do I declare a symbolic matrix in Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472486/how-do-i-declare-a-symbolic-matrix-in-octave/40824167#40824167)
3. [Octave symbolic expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068222/octave-symbolic-expression)
4. [Julia: how do I convert a symbolic expression to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357579/julia-how-do-i-convert-a-symbolic-expression-to-a-function)
5. [What is symbolic computation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395704/what-is-symbolic-computation)

Comment: This value `f(3)` is pretty meaningless since you have no control over the integration constant. You could as well get the mostly real expression `x^3/3 + log( 1 - cos(x) )/2 - log( 1 + cos(x) )/2` as result. Only definite integrals, like the difference `f(3)-f(0)` have results that are independent from the vagaries of the integration algorithm.

Comment: You are correct, this was just a random example I think of. The goal was to learn how to numerically evaluates symbolic expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`pretty`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html).

```
syms x;
x = x^3/3 + log( cos(x) - 1 )/2 - log( cos(x) + 1 )/2;
pretty(x)
```

which gives this:

```
                                     3
log(cos(x) - 1)   log(cos(x) + 1)   x
--------------- - --------------- + --
       2                 2           3
```

**Update (Since the question is edited):**

Make this function:

```
function x = f(y)
    syms a;
    f(a) = int ( a^2 + csc(a) );
    x = double(f(y));
end
```

Now when you call it using `f(3)`, it gives:

```
ans =
  11.6463 + 1.5708i
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you answered your own question by linking to [the other question about Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364660/matlab-how-do-i-convert-multivariable-symbolic-expression-to-a-function-that-fm).

Octave has an implementation of `matlabFunction` which is a wrapper for `function_handle` in the symbolic toolbox.

```
>> pkg load symbolic;
>> syms x;
>> y = x^3/3 + log( cos(x) - 1 )/2 - log( cos(x) + 1 )/2
y = (sym)

   3
  x    log(cos(x) - 1)   log(cos(x) + 1)
  -- + --------------- - ---------------
  3           2                 2

>> testfun = matlabFunction(y)
testfun =

@(x) x .^ 3 / 3 + log (cos (x) - 1) / 2 - log (cos (x) + 1) / 2

testfun(3)

>> testfun(3)
ans =  11.6463 +  1.5708i

>> testfun([3:1:5]')
ans =

   11.646 +  1.571i
   22.115 +  1.571i
   41.375 +  1.571i

>> testfun2 = matlabFunction(int ( x^2 + csc(x) ))
testfun2 =

@(x) x .^ 3 / 3 + log (cos (x) - 1) / 2 - log (cos (x) + 1) / 2

>> testfun2(3)
ans =  11.6463 +  1.5708i
>> testfun2([3:1:5]')
ans =

   11.646 +  1.571i
   22.115 +  1.571i
   41.375 +  1.571i
```

I'm sure there are other ways you could implement this, but it may allow you to avoid hardcoding your equation in a function.